# How to fix "Program type already present: androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, androidx

After migrating to AndroidX, I have the following issue as a result of the migration:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/2.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/3.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/4.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/5.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/6.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/7.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/8.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/9.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/10.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/11.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/12.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/13.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/14.jar, /home/lexy/AndroidStudioProjects/Testbucks/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/15.jar...
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor

Has anyone come across a similar issue, as I have not found any solutions to this problem in any forum.

Comment: I also upgraded to AndroidX and got this issue. :(  Still stuck with the below errors. - 

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Program type already present: androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complet

Comment: I don't think that issue has a solution yet, because i have searched everywhere, can't find any solution, the issue is not common...

Comment: I am also empty-handed. Looks like I will have to revert back to older libraries. :(

Comment: I am currently fed up, I don't know what to do, I can't move on

Comment: Hadn't you taken any backup? and if you refactored the code through "Migrate to Androidx", Android studio would have asked for the zipped backup. I moved back to the older codebase.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After migrating to AndroidX, I had a similar issue and the issue was because of Guava.
The way I resolved it was to include the following:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```

In the (Module:app), most solutions suggest that if you encounter this issue you include the following, in your module gradle:

```
implementation("android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0-alpha09") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture' 
}
```

This results in the following issue: Program type already present androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor.

Comment: Oh my God, this just worked like a magic, after 4weeks of searching, thanks so much....

Comment: This works!! I had exactly the same problem, and tried the other "suggested solutions",  and also got the same `androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor` error.