# Error - Android Duplicate Classes Found in Module

Tags: android, duplicates, androidx

Recently I have migrated to AndroidX after that it works fine, but suddenly when I try to make a build, it throws some error like some duplicate files have found in modules

Also I have enabled AndroidX in `gradle.properties`

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Error

```
Duplicate class androidx.concurrent.futures.DirectExecutor found in modules
concurrent-futures-1.0.0-alpha02.jar (androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.0.0-alpha02) 
and futures-1.0.0-alpha01.jar (androidx.concurrent:futures:1.0.0-alpha01)
```

I am using Viewmodel in my application, i add the viewmodel dependencies

```
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01"
```

And for viewmodel savestate, i add

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

My problem is when i remove the savestate dependency lib, every thing working fine.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: post your `gradle`

Comment: check this solution may this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038732/5370550